# How to check ElasticSearch version in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, elasticsearch

I am just curious on how to check ElasticSearch version in Linux?

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Just wanted to share my knowledge. It was a Q&A, not asking.

Comment: That's nice of you. But please spend a little more time on the site, especially on the [tour] and also on [meta] - specifically http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Comment: It's been upvoted, others have the question wanted the answer, perhaps another forum on StackExchange is a better home for this question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just send `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'`

And ElasticSearch will return its version in the respond, along with other info.

Comment: This works only in a case where you have only one version of ElasticSearch, and it's actually listening on port 9200 instead of another port, and it's listening to localhost and not on some other interface.

Comment: @JennyD you can also use `$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch -v` to get a version of specific Elasticsearch setup

Comment: @Derp That is a lot more functional, yes.

Comment: In Windows use `curl -XGET localhost:9200`

Comment: In OSX installed through brew. 
elasticsearch --version 
Version: 5.4.0, Build: 780f8c4/2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z, JVM: 1.8.0_131

Comment: I needed to login with username and password so I used: `curl --user "elastic:password" https://my-elastic.example.com/`.  Change username `elastic` and password `password` to your actual values. :-)